# Why is youtube API always create events in PDT timezone

Tags: youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

When I create event using youtube live streaming api, it creates it in PDT timezeone.

Sample Request :

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet%2Cstatus%2Cid%2CcontentDetails&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"snippet":{"scheduledStartTime":"2020-04-19T14:48:00.000Z","title":"sasasasa","channelId":"UCu4LgpgyV8zTqtlXiyn1-JA"},"status":{"privacyStatus":"public"},"contentDetails":{}}' \
  --compressed
```

Sample link of event created: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiqUAiJ26oE

How can I create it in IST timezone only.
Is there a solution possible. If I create it directly from youtube studio it works fine.